# How to create a trigger with threading.Timer?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, timer

I just discover python last month, I'm not a programmer at all. I'm trying to create my own software for an electronic instrument.
I actually need to create a trigger which will call a function each 0.04 ms 
(if it's possible). I tried with this:

In my first file Metronome.py:

```
class Metronome:

    def __init__(self, clip, _matrix):
        self.clip = clip
        self._matrix = _matrix
        self.inc = -1


    def _trigger(self): 
        self.inc = self.inc + 1
        self._matrix.get_button(self.inc, 1).send_value(GREEN_FULL)
        t = threading.Timer(1.0, self._trigger).start()
```

In a second file and a new class:

I import the previous function with:

```
from Metronome.py import Metronome
```

I call the previous function with:

```
Metronome(self.clip, self._matrix)._trigger()
```

In the `_trigger` function, `self._matrix.get_button(self.inc, 1).send_value(GREEN_FULL)` allows me to send a led feedback on my instrument interface. 
When I launch the program, I actually get the first led feedback on my instrument. However, the others take more than 1 second to setup and some of them appear at the same time. Also, after each feedback the time of the next one is increased (like 5/10 seconde). I don't get it!

Comment: I have tried to edit your code to beautify the question and make it comprehensible, but too many unknowns remain.

Comment: Please format the code properly and explain if it's within another class or not (too many references to `self.` otherwise)

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to do what you said, is this better ?

Comment: Also: the .py suffix is unnecessary in import statements

Comment: ehm.. Metronome is a class, not a function. You are instantiating an object of class Metronome and then calling its `_trigger` method. Which is fine. But, as per my previous question, why do you reference your `clip` and  `_matrix` parameters via `self.` ? Is that call being made within another class and those variables are its attributes?

Comment: Yes exactly ! Do you have an idea of why it's doesn't work well ?

Comment: the `_trigger` function will keep resetting the timer, therefore calling itself over and over. It lacks a termination condition.

Comment: the call of the _trigger method is done in an other class that the Metronome one. This class is in an other files and is call StepSequencer. In this class I have 2 variables: Self.clip and Self._matrix. I need it in the metronome class. This i why i call the _trigger method like this: Metronome(self.clip, self._matrix)._trigger()

Comment: A termination condition like what ?  Sorry I'm just beginning and I'm kind of lost. Thanks for your help

Comment: the `_trigger` method keeps creating a new timer, which calls the same method. BTW, I'd never do it like that. I'd sleep instead, until a specific condition is reached (e.g. the right button is pressed, etc)

Comment: a bigger portion of code is needed to be able to understand how you call/use the Metronome class and where.

Comment: ok i will upload this, in the mean time can you tell me if the threading.timer method could provide me a trigger each 0,01 second if  I set it well, or is this too fast  ?

Comment: when you create a timer a new thread is created. So you have two threads of execution (the main one and the new `timed' one). The `timed` one goes to sleep for the given amount of time and then wakes up and calls the `trigger` function. Then it terminates. But you are creating a new timer just before terminating.. therefore creating a new thread... an so on. Get it?

Answer (score 0):

apart from other issues on how the `Metronome` class is called (see comments above), I think the `_trigger` method should be more like:

```
def _trigger(self):
    while True:
        self.inc += 1
        self._matrix.get_button(self.inc, 1).send_value(GREEN_FULL)
        if (whatever_exit_condition):
            break
        time.sleep(time_interval_in_seconds)
```

if there's no exit condition, just remove the `if` block.

In a few words: avoid creating a new timer on every cycle.
Instead, create one Timer only, when you start calling the method:

```
t = threading.Timer(1.0, Metronome(self.clip, self._matrix)._trigger).start()
```

Here is a working example on how to use the timer:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from sys import argv
import time
import threading


def f():
    retry = 0
    while True:
        print "f, retry=", retry
        retry += 1
        if retry > 3:
            break
        time.sleep(2)
    print ("f exited")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(argv) <= 1:
        print "usage: %s num" % (argv[0],)
        exit(1)
    t = threading.Timer(1.0, f)
    t.start()
    for i in range(int(argv[1])):
        time.sleep(1)
        print "main, i=", i
```

if you run it with:

```
python timer.py 10
```

it outputs:

```
f, retry= 0
main, i= 0
main, i= 1
f, retry= 1
main, i= 2
main, i= 3
f, retry= 2
main, i= 4
main, i= 5
f, retry= 3
f exited
main, i= 6
main, i= 7
main, i= 8
main, i= 9
```

Basicallly the main thread is alive and does his thing, while the timer thread is created via the timer once and it keeps doing its bit (e.g. signal something to the user in your case), for a limited number of times (3), sleeping between each cycle.
I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Hi again ! So I tried what you said and it look like it works. However I still have a problem: `self._matrix.get_button(self.inc, 1).send_value(GREEN_FULL)` calls are only send when the loop stop (with the if statement). I think it's because of the buffer no ? How can I do to send the calls at each new step of the loop ?

Comment: uhm.. so partial good news then. I assume those calls show something on a button, but I ignore what the library/architecture is. It's all I can do on my side.

Comment: Ok, so I decided to create a thread immediately. So now, I don't use the timer method anymore, I use this : `t = threading.Thread(target=Metronome(self.clip, self._matrix)._trigger, args=()).start()` However I experienced a problem. I delete the while loop to understand it. The problem is that if I remove the time.sleep the button light up immediately (and that's ok)
but if I let it the button light up after a lot more than 2 seconde (like 5/6/10 seconds).
On the other side, if I call the _trigger method without a new thread like this `self.metronome._trigger()`
the time.sleep  is ok !

Comment: I almsot forgot, If I use join() my main thread wait (so it's freeze too) but the time.sleep work well !