# Only trigger thread when value changes (python)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, logic

I'm working on something that reads commands from a stream of data. I got stuck trying to work out making a re-usable non-blocking countdown in Python that works off a trigger. So I started a small program w/ just keyboard input and some basic threading to work out the logic. I found a few posts, and this post ([How to create a trigger with threading.Timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825811/how-to-create-a-trigger-with-threading-timer)) and it was very helpful. But I need some help with another part.

Right now my logic is along the lines of: "Each time the value of command is 1 call start"

How do I update my logic to be:
"if value of command is 1 call start, do not call start again as long as the value of command remains 1.

So its more of a value change detection than a normal if/else, or I have to track a boolean somewhere. I'm just not sure how to approach it.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import time
import threading
import random
from random import randint
import logging
from sys import argv


logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='[%(levelname)s] (%(threadName)-10s) %(message)s')

def countdown(pName,command):
    print("{0} countdown - command{1} ".format(pName,command))
    retry = 0
    while True:
        print("{0}:{1}".format(pName,retry))
        retry += 1
        if retry > randint(5,10):
            break
        time.sleep(1)
    print("{0} ended".format(pName))

def start(pName,command):
    print("starting countdown for: ",pName)
    t = threading.Thread(target=countdown,args=(pName,command))
    t.setName(pName)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    while 1:
        command = int(input("[1 or 2] >"))
        if command == 1:
            start("Salad",command)

        elif command == 2:
            start("Bingo",command)
```

This is pretty brute right now, but its just a first past to try and puzzle it out.

Thanks!

Comment: Have the thread set a flag when it starts and finishes? Writing/reading simple variables is thread safe, so just have the main thread and the sub thread access the same flag. Or you could use a thread lock as your flag.

Comment: Can you toss up an answer down below if you get a minute please? When you say flag I'm thinking true/false booleans. Which would work, can sometimes get hairy tho.

Comment: DJ McMayhem's answer essentially uses a built in flag, even better!

Comment: I know, its good, it just won't work for this particular setup. :-/ I'm going to try a bunch of booleans and then go from there.

Comment: @mishap_n What about it didn't work? I might have misunderstood what you want. If you let me know what was wrong, I'll update my answer.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/he79bkuX

The pastebin is the context for this logic. Its a _really super ugly program atm_, but basically, my triggers for starting a re-usable timer aren't in main, they're in a helper function where my data gets parsed and then commands get sent off (eventually) to some other functions and a serial port. I just never managed to get  "and not [process].isAlive()" to work in just a function outside of main. 101's suggestion of using true/false works, its just hairy.

So I guess: Can .isAlive() work in a function that isn't main?

Answer (score 1):

You want the function [isAlive](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.isAlive). First, you'll have to move your thread variable to the main function, so that main has the appropriate scope to call `thread.isAlive()`.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    tSalad = threading.Thread()
    tBingo = threading.Thread()
    while 1:
        command = int(input("[1 or 2] >"))
        if command == 1 and not tSalad.isAlive():
            tSalad = threading.Thread(target = countdown, args=("Salad", 1))
            start("Salad", tSalad)

        elif command == 2 and not tBingo.isAlive():
            tBingo = threading.Thread(target = countdown, args=("Bingo", 2))
            start("Bingo", tBingo)
```

Then you modify your 'start' function to take a thread argument:

```
def start(pName, t):
    print("starting countdown for: ",pName)
    t.setName(pName)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
```

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: I know this is right but I can't have things living in main for this one. Data stream gets pulled into main, everything gets sent out to helper functions. I tried some stuff with .isAlive() and it just would never fire as dead.

Comment: @mishap_n well, you gotta have *something* in main. I suppose you could keep it in a class, but then you'd have to keep an object of that class in main. However you do it, main needs to see the threads.